# How do I know whether a site is dynamically loaded (Javascript or otherwise) while i am scraping the website?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

For any given website, what is the test to know that the contents of the website are dynamically loaded using javascript ? I am trying to use Scrapy for web scraping.

Comment: Disable JavaScript on your browser and open the website.

Comment: Simple Solution, but it works, thanks a ton